# Use createObjectURL in Firefox javascript code module

Tags: firefox-addon, jsm

I want to use web workers in a javascript code module that load code from a blob. Typically this could be done in a webpage by calling "window.URL.createObjectURL" on the blob and giving the url generated by createObjectURL to the worker. Is this possible in a javascript code module, despite there being no window.URL object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import the URL constructor

```js
Components.utils.importGlobalProperties(['URL']);
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to have worked. Is Components.utils.importGlobalProperties documented anywhere?

Comment: I don't think so. The properties supported are `indexedDB`, `XMLHttpRequest`, `TextEncoder`, `TextDecoder`, `URL`, `atob` and `btoa`.

Comment: Since what version of Firefox is this supported? I was also trying to use `createObjectURL` and came across this post. Is this the only way to get to createObjectURL and revokeObjectURL?

Comment: @Noitidart importGlobalProperties is available since Gecko 27. AFAIK the methods you mention are not accessible otherwise.

Comment: Cool thanks man, URL.createObjectUrl was available to window scope before 27 though right?

Comment: @Noitidart yes, but [not that much](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL.URL#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Oh cool it started in FF26, how would people accomplish this prior to FF26? just curuious now, i dont have an application for it.